# find punctual element in array with two elements javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-map

I have the next situation:

1). one array with months from 1 to 12 and values at 0:

```
var months = [[1,0], [2,0], [3,0], [4,0], [5,0], [6,0], [7,0], [8,0],
              [9,0], [10,0], [11,0], [12,0], [13,0]];
```

2). another small array which represents the times a user has connected to the site:

```
 data1 = [[1, 40], [2, 50]]
```

what I want to do is to overlapp both arrays, running over values in array months that are in array data1.

So result has to be:

```
data1 = [[1,40], [2,50], [3,0], [4,0], [5,0], [6,0], [7,0], [8,0], 
         [9,0], [10,0], [11,0], [12,0], [13,0]];
```

can't find the way to access to the first element of each array (in months), this is what I've tried so far:

```
 for (var x = months.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
    for (var j = monthConn.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        console.log(monthConn[j]); 
        for (var p = 0; p < monthConn[j].length; p++) {
           console.log(monthConn[j][p]);
        };
        // console.log(months[x].indexOf(monthConn[j]));
     };
    };
```

for what I'm getting in console.log:

```
["5", "2"]
5
2
```

how can I do this?

Comment: you could make months an object with month as key and value as value

Comment: @depperm I need to leave it like it is because I'm modifying a plugin that makes statistical graphs :s and it uses arrays

Comment: Not much related maybe: just wondering there are 13 elements, you said 12

Comment: @vinayakj 12 elemets because each of them represents a month, and 13 is to leave a blanck space in the chart, so it will always be 0

Comment: ok.. got it.. this was important..so while comparing no need to compare for last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to iterate over `data1`, and access the `n-1`-th position of months, where `n`is the first element of every entry:

```
var months = [[1,0], [2,0], [3,0], [4,0], [5,0], [6,0], [7,0], [8,0], [9,0], [10,0], [11,0], [12,0], [13,0]]

var data1 = [[1, 40], [2, 50]]

// clone months array
var overlapped = months.slice()

// for every data1 value, update corresponding month
data1.forEach(function(monthData){
  overlapped[monthData[0]-1][1] = monthData[1]
})

// et voilá
console.log(overlapped)
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngL3rp3d/).

Comment: Nice use of  `.slice`  to clone the array, and overlapping logic too

Comment: I know now how to use slice function, very useful

Answer (score 0):

```
var months = [[1,0], [2,0], [3,0], [4,0], [5,0], [6,0], [7,0],
              [8,0], [9,0], [10,0], [11,0], [12,0], [13,0]];
var monthConn = [[1,40],[2,50]];
var data = [];
for (var x = 0, l = months.length; x < l; x++) {
     data[x] = [0,0];
    for (var j = monthConn.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
           data[x][0] = months[x][0];
           data[x][1] = months[x][1];
           if(monthConn[j][0] == data[x][0]){
                  data[x][1]=monthConn[j][1];
                  break;
           }
    }
}
console.dir(months)
console.dir(data)
```

Comment: hey thnx for the answer. It's only registering [1,40] in data array but not [2,50]

Comment: BTW do you want output data in separate array or same `months` array should be modified

Comment: in another array so I keep doing this with other user's connections

Comment: I think you should go with moonwave99's answer, seems very small and nice logic.